# why the sweep phase of cms does not have to stop the world?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

I have a question on cms sweep phase,  the sweep phase will not stop the world ,considering the below case , a pointer c is null which will not be marked as reachable , after remark phase , the c pointer is modified to be a new object,or do the things like c=b, b is unreachable ,but if c points the it ,it becomes reachable, for these two cases ,will the c will be collected? it is not marked on remark phase ,so if it is collected, i think it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a huge misconception in your question. Garbage collectors collect *objects*, i.e. the memory occupied by them, not pointers.

Pointers are traversed in the marking phase to determine, which objects are reachable. When your pointer `c` is `null`, it doesn’t point to any object and there is nothing to traverse. Whether there are unreachable objects can’t be determined from `c`, it just doesn’t contribute to this process. All that matters, is which pointers *do* point to an object, as these objects are reachable. All objects not encountered during the traversal are unreachable.

Since being unreachable implies that *no pointer to the object exists*, no subsequent pointer assignment can make an unreachable object reachable. When you do `c = b`, there are only two possible scenarios, 1) `b` is `null`, hence `c` will be `null` too after the assignment or 2) `b` points to an object which, of course, has been marked as reachable during the marking phase, so now there’s one more pointer to that reachable object, which doesn’t change its reachable nature.

The only change that may happen during a concurrent sweeping phase, is that an object marked as reachable may become unreachable concurrently, e.g. if `c` was the only pointer to an object, a concurrent `c = b` makes that object unreachable. This, however, just implies that this object is still treated like being reachable in this sweeping phase and needs to be collected in the next garbage collection cycle.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, is it possible that an obj in new generation points to an obj in old generation after remark phase? there are two cases, one of which is that obj in old has already been marked, this case ,it has no problem,what if the obj in old is not marked ? will this happen?

Comment: To assign a reference to an old object to a field of a new object, you need to have the reference before the operation. So you could do something like `newObj.field = oldRef; oldRef = null;` to only have the new object pointing to the old object, but note that at any time, there is at least one reference to the old object (and the marking phase stops the world). So the old object will always be marked as reachable.